# Rails migration for C++

Tags: c++, migration

Is there a tool for C++ that is at least remotely similar to Rails migrations?

Comment: You will have to explain to us C++ types what "rails migrations" means and/or does.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Comment: Similar in what way? Syntax? Logic?

Comment: Possibly both :) But preferrably logic

Answer (score 0):

I think anything "similar" to Rails migrations is going to be somewhat specific to an ORM or other framework - the ease of use comes from the fact that you migrate from one object model to another.

Since C++ doesn't have an ORM or any other built-in way of specifying a database schema, I don't see how there can be a schema migration tool "for C++". Perhaps if you specify what tools you're using, the question will be more eye-catching for those who know what's available.

If you can express your migration purely in terms of the database tables, then you could use a migration tool that's independent of any ORM. But then you wouldn't actually need it to be in C++, since it's just issuing SQL (or whatever database) commands. There are plenty of tools around (maybe search "database schema migration"), although I'm afraid I'm basically ignorant in this area, and can't recommend one. As long as you have an adaptor to your database, you could even use Rails...

Comment: What I would really love to have is a migration tool that is DB-agnostic. That is, a tool that would pick up, say, a schema-definition file and alter the DB, regardless of whether its' MSSQL or MySQL.

There actually exists an ORM for C++, http://dtemplatelib.sourceforge.net/ but it doesn't offer migratons...

I guess it would be easier to just bundle Ruby with the application :)